# How to choose target API level when creating a new project in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-api-levels

I am new to android development and Android Studio. I also have a physical device which runs android version 5.0.1. When I try to debug an app from Android Studio on my device I don't get the behavior as in the emulator.

My project's target API level (when I create it) is always 23 (Android 6.0 Marshmallow). Although the minimum API level is 17 (Android 4.2 Jelly Bean) I want to know how to set the target API level on project creation. Is this possible with the current version of Android Studio (1.4.1)?

Comment: You can set `targetSdkVersion` to anything you want in `build.gradle` file

Comment: You can always manually modify the value that you find in the gradle file associated to your project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to choose the target API level using the New Project wizard in Android Studio currently (1.4.1). It should always be the latest version available anyway.

From http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/basics/supporting-devices/platforms.html#sdk-versions:

> To allow your app to take advantage of these changes and ensure that
>   your app fits the style of each user's device, you should set the
>   targetSdkVersion value to match the latest Android version available.

To modify it after project creation just edit the `targetSdkVersion` value in your `build.gradle` file.

Comment: So I just have to modify the value `targetSdkVersion` in `build.gradle`?

Comment: Yes you can set that to whatever API version you want