# Your application is currently targeting API level 23. However, it must target API level 26 to a minimum in order to benefit from the latest APIs

Tags: android-studio, google-play

Please, I'm in the process of publishing an app on Google Play and I've had a problem with the version of the API, I've already tried to change the API version to the latest version but it does not work .
the error message is :**Your application is currently targeting API level 23. However, it must target API level 26 to a minimum in order to benefit from the latest APIs, which are optimized for security and performance. Set the target API level of your application to at least 26.**

here it is my **app.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.me.guide.myapp"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "DEVELOP-EMS"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        debuggable false
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
} 
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0'
}
```

thanks?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/33517184/62576 I see where it says `targetSdkVersion 23`. Did you try changing that to `26` instead?

Comment: yes, i did but it doesn't work

Comment: You have several `23` entries in your app.gradle. Certainly you can put some effort into solving this?

Answer (score 1):

Change your `targetSdkVersion` to 26. You say this doesn't work. This is the required solution, so can you say more about why it doesn't work?